# Communication Issue between the Domain Server and the Exchange Server

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

The Domain Controller Server (Windows Server 2016) has IP's for DNS of 168 and 170

The Exchange Server (Windows Server 2019) can not ping 170 with the command prompt.

The ping of domain returns 170 and 14.

The ping of 14 times out probably invalid.

I am trying to find away to have the exchange server have connectivity with the domain server.

**Exchange Server Command Prompt**

```
C:\Users\administrator.ADVSYSTEMS> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : VSDCA2K16MAIL01
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : advsystems.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : advsystems.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : advsystems.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-67-A6-06
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e476:c122:6983:e4a5%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.103.60(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.103.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.103.170
                                       192.168.103.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**Domain Server Command Prompt**

```
C:\Users\Administrator.ADVSYSTEMS>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : VSDCA2K16DC01
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : advsystems.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : advsystems.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : advsystems.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-67-A6-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1972:89b7:b976:e374%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.103.170(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.103.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 33559901
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-88-E8-7F-00-15-5D-67-A6-00
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       192.168.103.1
                                       127.0.0.7
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:2851:2871:464:2ea0:9d40:2acd(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::464:2ea0:9d40:2acd%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 134217728
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-88-E8-7F-00-15-5D-67-A6-00
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.advsystems.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : advsystems.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `192.168.103.1`? Your router? It should appear nowhere in your DNS configuration. Get rid of it everywhere for DNS. When you're running Active Directory, all your DNS should be contained within the Active Directory domain.

Your domain controller can do recursive DNS lookups on its own. It should not be configured with an external source for DNS.

Comment: Its the Exchange Server's Default Gateway